# USB-C cord with tight contact

Tags: usb, usb-c

I have noticed that many USB charging cables get disconnected from the phone (or sometimes the charger) rather easily. I am looking for the opposite: a USB-C to USB-C, or USB-C to USB-A cable, that will not easily come unstuck by accident, say if someone trips over the cord.

Are there any brands of cables that are known for having a particularly tight connection? Or is there some other solution?

Comment: Be aware that easy disconnection can be a safety feature, as with the magnetic connectors on MacBooks - if the cord rips away when you trip over it, you don't damage yourself or something else expensive instead by pulling it over.

Comment: Thank you. I am aware of that, but I would prefer the opposite.